# Nextjs: How to call response content from dynamic route inside other component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, url-routing

I follow this [tutorial](https://developers.wpengine.com/blog/crash-course-build-a-simple-headless-wordpress-app-with-next-js-wpgraphql) and it works. Now, I can access some dynamic route directly like this: http://localhost:3000/opening2 when I code like this in [uri].js:

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { client } from '../lib/apollo';
import Footer from "/components/Footer/Footer.js";
import Header from "/components/Header/Header.js";

export default function SlugPage({ post }) {

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Blog</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"></link>
      </Head>

      <main>
        <div className="siteHeader">
          <h1 className="title">
            {post.title}
          </h1>
          <p>✍️  &nbsp;&nbsp;{`${post.author.node.firstName} ${post.author.node.lastName}`} | ️ &nbsp;&nbsp;{new Date(post.date).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
        </div>
        <article dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }}>
        </article>
      </main>

      <Footer></Footer>

    </div>
  )
}


export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const GET_POST_BY_URI = gql`
        query GetPostByURI($id: ID!) {
          post(id: $id, idType: URI) {
            title
            content
            date
            uri
            author {
              node {
                firstName
                lastName
              }
            }
          }
        }
  `

  const response = await client.query({
    query: GET_POST_BY_URI,
    variables: {
      id: params.uri
    }
  })

  const post = response?.data?.post
  return {
    props: {
      post
    }
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = ['/opening2']
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking'
  }
}
```

Now, I want to call its content (http://localhost/opening2) directly from a components Featured.js:

```
export default function Featured(post) {
    return (
        <div><Link href={post.uri} className={"card"}>
                  <a className="card">
                      <h3>{post.title} &rarr;</h3>
                  </a>
             </Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But when I access http://localhost/featured, gave me error like this:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title')

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: `Featured` is a page or just a component?

Comment: Featured is a component

Comment: I don't see any relation between `Featured` component and `opening2` page, could you share `opening2` page's code as well?

Comment: @NickVu opening2 is staticPath from [uri].js. I updated to complete code [uri].js.

Comment: Are you trying to use the `Featured` component inside the dynamic route as `<Featured post={post} />`? If so, then your component signature is not correct, and should be modified to `export default function Featured({ post }) { ... }` (noticed the `{}` around `post`).

Comment: Also, if `Featured` is meant to be a simple component and not a route, then it should be moved out of the `pages` folder. Only page components should be under `pages` as Next.js routing is based on that folder structure.

Comment: @juliomalves Featured is a component, not a page. I have dynamic content from [uri].js and make a staticpath /opening2. If I call directly http://localhost/opening2, it works. But, I want to call the content from featured.js, so I can call Featured whenever I want from any page. Is impossible to do?

Comment: If you want to call `Featured` as a page then it needs to be a page component. It won't get the required data otherwise.

Comment: @juliomalves can you give me example about what you said? I didn’t understand.

Comment: If you want the `Featured` component to be directly accessible when going to `/featured` in the browser, then `Featured` needs to be a page component, i.e. `pages/featured.js` with its own `getStaticProps` function to retrieve the data.

Comment: as page, i already did. but as i wrote, i want to do that as a component, not as page. So, i have featured component and call it form a page.